# Swift 3 sound play

Tags: swift3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

Ok I have looked into this and have tried many different ways to play a sound when a button is clicked.

How would I play a sound when a button is clicked in swift 3?
I have my sound in a folder named Sounds and the name is ClickSound.mp3

Comment: It is an old question, but it could be mentioned that it is a recommended way to use wav or caf audio formats (rather than mp3) for short sounds.

Comment: @Whirlwind can you explain why?  I'm actually super interested in this, since I've got an app I'm working on with short sounds where I'm currently using mp3 for them. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: @SRMR Just google about compressed and decompressed formats on iOS. For example, a wav file has no compression, means you will get best quality, low cpu impact but big disk space consumption. So this is ideal for short sounds because they dont take up too much space on disc. On the other side, mp3 is compressed, so it will save your diskspace, means it will keep your app size low, but it will be decompressed into ram, and when decompressed it will take the same amount of space as uncompressed sound. Also decompression makes an impact on cpu in some percent... Hope this make sense for you.

Comment: So mp3 is ideal for background music

Comment: @Whirlwind this is great, thanks for explaining and pointing me in a direction I can track down more about now too re: compressed and decompressed formats.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

User below this function

```
 //MARK:- PLAY SOUND
func playSound() {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ClickSound", withExtension: "mp3")!

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        guard let player = player else { return }

        player.prepareToPlay()
        player.play()
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }
}
```

first  import AudioToolbox
       import AVFoundation

Hope it works :)

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: This is the code                                                                                           func playSound() {
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "ClickSound", withExtension: "mp3")!
        
        do {
            let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard  player == player else { return }
            
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.description)
        }
    }

Comment: You should create a global reference for "player" .add    var player:AVAudioPlayer?

Comment: var player: AVAudioPlayer? declare it as global.

Answer (score 14):

You have to keep the player from being disposed of, get it in a property of your view controller

> The only real catch is that you must store your player as a property
>   or other variable that won't get destroyed straight away – if you
>   don't, the sound will stop immediately.

[source:](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-play-sounds-using-avaudioplayer)

```
var player : AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound(){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "alert", ofType:"mp3")!
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            self.player = sound
            sound.numberOfLoops = 1
            sound.prepareToPlay()
            sound.play()
        } catch {
            print("error loading file")
            // couldn't load file :(
        }
}
```

Comment: Your comment about the destroyed property saved me. Thanks.

Comment: @LenD You are most welcome, I am glad I could help :)

Answer (score 6):

You might want to use [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound). It lets you play sounds easily in Swift.

```
Sound.play(file: "ClickSound.mp3")
```

Answer (score 3):

A much easier way to do this is to put the following line of code in your button pressed function (Note: Only works in sprite kit):

```
run(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("ClickSound.mp3", waitForCompletion: false))
```

Hope this helps :)