# Play local song NOT in background Swift 3

Tags: ios, audio, swift3, avfoundation, media-player

Before posting this question I search on internet and here on StackOverflow, but I didn't found how to play a song **not** in background.

Every *"Play local song tutorial"* shows how to play the song in background, but I need to play it so that when you open Control Center and swipe to right it shows the name, cover and the play/pause button of the song, [like normal song do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXeZc.png)

Another problem of playing songs in background is that when the app get close, is automatically stop the song, and thats not the idea of a **mp3 app**.

I have tried `AVFoundation` and `MediaPlayer`, even [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound), but they all play the song in background.

Any idea on how can I play a local song **not** in background?

---

Thanks

---

Comment: I think this  link is useful your answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036146/how-to-play-a-sound-in-swift-2-and-3

Comment: Nice answers, but it still in background.