# Playing sound on UIButton pressed with different tags

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, sender

I am trying to implement a xylophone where I want to play different sounds on tap of different buttons which I merged it to one IBAction function and have differentiated with different tags.

```
@IBAction func keysPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

I am importing AVFoundation but not getting the exact function to call to play sounds

I need a function which I can call in each If else statement differentiating buttons with tags to play sounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to play a sound using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036146/how-to-play-a-sound-using-swift)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a question on how to get different buttons to play different sounds, you could subclass UIButton to include a field for tracking which note it is, and call the correct function based on that.

```
class XyloKey: UIButton {
    var note: String
}
```

And then in your view controller:

```
let key = XyloKey()
key.note = "C5"
key.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playNote(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

And assuming you name your files by note name (e.g. "note_C5.mp3").

```
func playNote(_ sender: XyloKey) {
    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("note_\(sender.note)", withExtension: "mp3")
    playSound(url)
}
```

Where playSound plays the sound of the passed file. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036146/how-to-play-a-sound-using-swift) passed in the flag above for details.