# Play reminder sound SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, avfoundation

I understand I can play a sound from my own library, like:
[How to play a sound using Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036146/how-to-play-a-sound-using-swift#32036291)

But how can I use the already existing default Reminder Alerts sounds that iPhone has? Just to put it into context in a simple button press?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
import AVFoundation

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1026)
```

where the number 1026 is the SystemSound id.

Comment: Where can I find the sounds with their corresponding symbols?

Comment: here is another link: https://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/AudioServices