# SwiftUI add sound effect when a button is pressed

Tags: swiftui

I would like to add a sound effect when a button is pressed in my app for SwiftUI. The button has another feature, but I just want to add a sound effect. I have found information for previous versions of Xcode using UIkit, but I'm not understanding how to do it in SwiftUI.

Edit: I'm very new to programming if that explains my lack of knowledge.

Comment: You should be able to add an [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioplayer) to the button's action parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

from answer:
[Play reminder sound SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61310578/play-reminder-sound-swiftui/61313673#61313673)

you can use this simple method:

```
import AVFoundation

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1026)
```

where the number 1026 is the SystemSound id.

Comment: That worked perfectly and the ladder sound effect turned out to fit well enough.

Comment: great, could you then mark the answer as correct please.

Comment: Not working for iOS 15 in Xcode 15