# How Can I Get A List of Available System Sounds in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, audio

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126124/using-existing-system-sounds-in-ios-app-swift), but it's a bit aged. It looks like that directory access is no longer available for [the example app](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) they recommend.

[The Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/system_sound_services#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound) doesn't seem to have what I need, either.

What I need is to be able to list the built-in sounds (not provide my own), and allow a user of my app to choose one to play.

Sounds simple enough, eh?

***UPDATE:***

Here is the relevant code in the example app mentioned below:

```
NSURL *directoryURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds"];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObject:NSURLIsDirectoryKey];

NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator = [fileManager
                                     enumeratorAtURL:directoryURL
                                     includingPropertiesForKeys:keys
                                     options:0
                                     errorHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                         // Handle the error.
                                         // Return YES if the enumeration should continue after the error.
                                         return YES;
                                     }];

for (NSURL *url in enumerator) {
    NSError *error;
    NSNumber *isDirectory = nil;
    if (! [url getResourceValue:&isDirectory forKey:NSURLIsDirectoryKey error:&error]) {
        // handle error
    }
    else if (! [isDirectory boolValue]) {
        [audioFileList addObject:url];
    }
}
```

The problem is that the enumerator is always empty. I suspect this may be a security/sandbox issue.

Comment: I haven't tried the code, but this looks like it should give you what you want: https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

Comment: Thanks. That's the app I pointed to. It is supposed to list the sound files in the library directory, but when I run it in iOS 10+, I get a big fat nothing.

Comment: Yeah, after a little more reading that code may only work on jail-break... Not sure what all you *can* get from system sounds, based on this note on Apple's docs: `**Note** System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface sound effects are not available to your iOS application. For example, using the kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert constant as a parameter to the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function will not play anything.`

Comment: Yeah...I'm starting to grok that. I may have to come up with a library of sounds, turning my svelte little app into a wallowing hog.

Comment: OTOH, some short alert sounds shouldn't take too much space :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll stick with a few short (less than a second) beeps.

Comment: @DonMag If you word your response as an answer, I'll greencheck you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading up on this, you can find code to get a list of system sound files - but only on a "jail break" device.

Based on this note on Apple's docs ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/1405202-audioservicesplayalertsound?preferredLanguage=occ)), it sounds like (sorry for the pun) we won't have much luck in trying to access the "internal" sound clips:

> **Note** System-supplied alert sounds and system-supplied user-interface sound effects are not available to your iOS application. For example, using the kSystemSoundID_UserPreferredAlert constant as a parameter to the AudioServicesPlayAlertSound function will not play anything.