# Safer way to get system audio URL

Tags: swift, avfoundation

This is how I get a system sound URL:

```
let audioURL = URL(string: "/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tock.caf")
```

But if in future the directory will be changed, the app will point to an invalid sound URL. Is there a safer way to get the URL?

PS: I need to create an AVAudioPlayer object in order to set the volume, so I can't use AudioServicesPlaySystemSound().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using existing system sounds in iOS App \[swift|](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126124/using-existing-system-sounds-in-ios-app-swift)

Comment: @Scriptable No it's not the same thing. I need to create my own AVAudioPlayer in order to set the volume. AudioServicesPlaySystemSound() doesn't allow to set the volume.

Comment: Okay, please be specific in the question

Answer (score 0):

This could be your safe solution. Get URLs using `FileManager.`

`let urls = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .systemDomainMask)`