# Add System Sound to iOS remote notification in UNNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, remote-notifications

I am successfully modifying my remote notification payload using the UINotificationServiceExtension.

I want to change the alert sound based on the user's choice here.  In order to do that I need to assign a UINotificationSound object to the bestAttemptContent:

```
bestAttemptContent.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(rawValue: "alertTone.caf"))
```

This will work for tones which I have created and imported into my project.  One named alertTone.caf in the above example.

However, I want to use the system alert tones instead of my own.  I know I can set the default tone but I want access to other custom tones.  Is there anyway at all to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't reference the system sounds for UNNotificationSound, but you can try to play the sound when you receive the notification in the service extension.

```
// import
import AVFoundation

// create a sound ID, in this case its the tweet sound.
let systemSoundID: SystemSoundID = 1016

// Play the correct sound when the notification is received in the service extension
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (systemSoundID)
```

Source for playing system sounds [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31126124/using-existing-system-sounds-in-ios-app-swift).

[This](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary) is a list of all the system sound ids that you can use for reference.