# How to get a list of ringtones?

Tags: flutter

I want the user to be able to choose a ringtone/notification sound for a notification and I need to get the list of available ringtones. Is there a way of doing this in Flutter?

Comment: Hello, an API ([RingtoneManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager)) exists for android, but in iOS I think you cannot list system ringtones. That is probably why there is no Flutter plugin available for this.

Comment: Oh actually using Swift you can play iOS system sounds (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31126202/10122791))

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to access my systems ringtones in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70019114/i-want-to-access-my-systems-ringtones-in-flutter)