# I want to access my systems ringtones in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

Is there any way to get all the **Ringtones** of the phone using **flutter**, and set the chosen one as the default ringtone of my app?

thanks in advance

Comment: you may refer to this link https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ringtone_player

Comment: I tried it but it plays the default ones. what I want instead is to get them all and let the user choose which one he wants.

Comment: then I think you have to use MethodChannel to write platform specific code to get the llst.

Comment: thanks, man that's what I'm gonna do.

Comment: pleased to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it done using native code

1. First you would create those things on the Flutter side.

   ```
   // here where your ringtones will be stored
   List<Object?> result = ['Andromeda'];

   // this is the channel that links flutter with native code
   static const channel = MethodChannel('com.example.pomo_app/mychannel');

   // this method waits for results from the native code 
   Future<void> getRingtones() async {
       try {
         result = await channel.invokeMethod('getAllRingtones');
       } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
         print('Exception: $ex.message');
       }
     }
   ```
2. Know you need to implement the native code. Go to MainActivity.kt

   ```
   // add the name of the channel that we made in flutter code
   private val channel = "com.example.pomo_app/mychannel"

   // add this method to handle the calls from flutter
   MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, channel)
     .setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
               when (call.method) {
                   "getAllRingtones" -> {
                       result.success(getAllRingtones(this))
                   }



   // this function will return all the ringtones names as a list
   private fun getAllRingtones(context: Context): List<String> {

     val manager = RingtoneManager(context)
     manager.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)

     val cursor: Cursor = manager.cursor

     val list: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
     while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       val notificationTitle: String = cursor.getString(RingtoneManager.TITLE_COLUMN_INDEX)
       list.add(notificationTitle)
     }
     return list
   }
   ```

that's it I hope this is helpful. any questions let me know.

Comment: Is there a way to play the retrieved sounds?

Answer (score 1):

I've made [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_system_ringtones) for this a while back

Comment: Thank you very much for the plugin. Is there a way to play the retrieved sounds?